# visual basic Function to return exit sub

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a visual basic application for a friend. Anyway I am trying to create a function that returns "exit sub" to the sub calling the function. I have seen some ways around this by returning a value like 1 or 2 and inserting a if in calling sub. just wondering if there is a short hand for returning exit sub that I haven't learned yet.

```
Private Sub Button1.click() Handles Button1.Click

tryactive()

endsub    
Private Function tryactive()
        Try
            AppActivate("your aplication")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim msgboxresponse = MsgBox("please start your application", 0, "Can't find your application")
            If msgboxresponse = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
                Exit Sub <------ this is the problem i want to send this back to calling sub
            End If
        End Try

    End Function
```

Code is much bigger and a lot more buttons. That's why i'm asking if there's a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in VB.NET that a Function has to return a type, otherwise it's a `Sub`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you cannot use an ***Exit Sub*** inside a ***Function***. It should be an ***Exit Function***. But based on what you want to happen (I guess), try this.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click

    If TryActive() = False Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    'Your code you want to execute if TryActive() is True

End Sub

Private Function TryActive() as Boolean
    Try
        AppActivate("your aplication")
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim msgboxresponse = MsgBox("please start your application", 0, "Can't find your application")
        If msgboxresponse = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            Return False
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: If `TryActive()` is marked as a `Function`, it needs a return type, something like `Function TryActive() As Boolean` maybe.

Comment: so I could use 'Sub Button1... If Not TryActive() then Exit Sub End If "rest of code if successful" End Sub

Comment: Yep. Check my new answer. Just as like that.